# iPhone, how do I set the background of a view like the settings screens gray style?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm creating a settings screen, its a child screen and won't push to another screen. I don't want to use a table view. But I need to have the screen look like other settings screens, with the gray sort of background, like this...

[image]

Comment: You mean you don't want to use a UITableView with a style UITableViewStyleGrouped

Comment: Why don't you want to use a UITableView? That's how you'd easily achieve what you want...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
```